# Increment numbers in char array separated by different delimiters

Tags: c++, c

I have string like this **1-2,4^,14-56**
I am expecting output **2-3,5^,15-57**

```
char input[48];
int temp;
char *pch;

pch = strtok(input, "-,^");

while(pch != NULL)
{
    char tempch[10];
    temp = atoi(pch);
    temp++;
    itoa(temp, tempch, 10);
    memcpy(pch, tempch, strlen(tempch));
    pch = strtok(NULL, "-,^");
}
```

After running through this if I print **input** it prints only 2 which is first character of the updated string. It does not print all characters in the string. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: `strtok` isn't the right tool for this job, so unless you're required to use it, I would use a simple `for` loop that checks each character with `isdigit`, and does the numeric conversion without using `atoi` or `itoa`. Then there's the 99 bug. If the input string contains 99, and you increment it to 100, the string needs to grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plain C, use the library function `strtod`. Other than `atoi`, this can update a pointer to the next unparsed character:

> long **strtol** (const char *restrict *str*, char **restrict *endptr*, int *base*);
>   ...
>   The **strtol()** function converts the string in *str* to a long value. [...] If *endptr* is not NULL, **strtol()** stores the address of the first invalid character in **endptr*.

Since there may be more than one 'not-a-digit' character between the numbers, skip them with the library function `isdigit`. I placed this at the start of the loop so it would not accidentally convert a string such as `-2,3` to `-1,4` -- the initial `-2` would be picked up first! (And if that is a problem elsewhere, there is also a `strtoul`.)

Since it appears you want the result in a *char* string, I use `sprintf` to copy the output into a buffer, which must be large enough for your possible input *plus* extra characters caused by a decimal overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *inputString = "1-2,4^,14-56";
    char *next_code_at = inputString;
    long result;
    char dest[100], *dest_ptr;

    printf ("%s\n", inputString);

    dest[0] = 0;
    dest_ptr = dest;
    while (next_code_at && *next_code_at)
    {
        while (*next_code_at && !(isdigit(*next_code_at)))
        {
            dest_ptr += sprintf (dest_ptr, "%c", *next_code_at);
            next_code_at++;
        }
        if (*next_code_at)
        {
            result = strtol (next_code_at, &next_code_at, 10);
            if (errno)
            {
                perror ("strtol failed");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else
            {
                if (result < LONG_MAX)
                    dest_ptr += sprintf (dest_ptr, "%ld", result+1);
                else
                {
                    fprintf (stderr, "number too large!\n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n", dest);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Input:  1-2,4^,14-56
Output: 2-3,5^,15-57
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two major problems with this code:
First of all,

```
pch = strtok(input, ",");
```

When applied to the string `1-2,4^,14-56` will return the token `1-2`.

When you call `atoi("1-2")` you'll get `1`, which gets converted to `2`.

You can fix this by changing the first strtok to `pch = strtok(NULL, "-,^");`

Second of all, strtok modifies the string, which means that you lose the original delimiter found.  As this looks like a homework exercise, I'll leave you to figure out how to get around this.

Comment: Is there any way I can save the delimiter after going through each `strtok` call?

Comment: Not with this code. But if you ran it on a copy of the buffer, and observed that the token that was just converted to a NULL was at position
sum(tokens) + sum(delimiters),  you'd be able to find its index in the original array.

Answer (score 2):

I think this could by easier using regular expressions(and C++ instead of C of course):

Complete exmaple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    // Your test string.
    std::string input("1-2,4^,14-56");
    // Regex representing a number.
    std::regex number("\\d+");

    // Iterators for traversing the test string using the number regex.
    auto ri_begin = std::sregex_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), number);
    auto ri_end = std::sregex_iterator();


    for (auto i = ri_begin; i != ri_end; ++i)
    {
        std::smatch match = *i;                             // Match a number.
        int value = std::stoi(match.str());                 // Convert that number to integer.
        std::string replacement = std::to_string(++value);  // Increment 1 and convert to string again.

        input.replace(match.position(), match.length(), replacement); // Finally replace.
    }

    std::cout << input << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2-3,5^,15-57
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` modifies the string you pass to it. Either use `strchr` or something like that to find the delimiters or make a copy of the string to work on.